# How to sort elements of array in natural order with mixed (letters and numbers) elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, google-apps-script, google-sheets

i am trying to create google-form which is used to register students agreements on practice. Every agreement is registered and got agreement number which format is Last to digits of current year-T-number of agreement at this year/M. For example for now it is 17-T-11/M. The number of agreement currently is written by person which is responsible for practice. 
Here is code of script below:

```
function onChange(e) 
{
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[1];
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();
  var comboValues = ['16-T-105/M']; 

   // removing titles from 0 column and 1 line (titles)
  for (var i = 1; i <= values.length; i++) {
    var v = values[i] && values[i][0];
    v && comboValues.push(v)
  }

  // Sort the values
  comboValues.sort(
    function(a, b) {
      if (b.toLowerCase() < a.toLowerCase()) return -1;
      if (b.toLowerCase() > a.toLowerCase()) return 1;
      return 0;
    }
  );
  Logger.log(comboValues);

  // google-form modification
  var form = FormApp.openById('1SHgVIosoE34m9cny9EQySljvgnRpzffdFEZe-kzNOzA');

  var items = form.getItems();
  for (i = 4; i < items.length; i++) {
    Logger.log("ID: " + items[i].getId(), ': ' + items[i].getType());
  }

  form.getItemById('2087613006').asListItem().setChoiceValues(comboValues);
```

I got issue which is related with lexicographical order. Person which register agreement choose from list last registered agreement number: i tryed to do that last registered agreement number will always be at list top. As time when i started this everything was fine (it started with number 16-T-105/M), but new year come and soon after 17-T-10/M agreement was registered i got issue, that 17-T-10/M was not on list top. Soon i realised that this happens because script use lexicographical order and "thinks" that 2 is more than 10. So i understood that i somehow will have to change that order and do that 2 is less than 10, 11 is less than 101 and so on. 
My question is how to do that? I guess that i need to sort array elements in natural order - but i do not have idea how to do this.
I tryed to google how to do it , but result was not satisfactory - maybe my knowledge of coding is pretty limited (i am PhD student of Psychology, not Informatics) :)
Maybe someone will help how to solve that problem.

Updates: 
Link to spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FH5qYTrLUNI2SCrcaqlwgu8lzAylaTkZsiALg0zIpCM/edit#gid=1620956794

Link to google-form (Copy of actual form): https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSerJfkv1dgHexUwxppXNyhb46twOZgvEMOIVXSOJoED3SLmyQ/viewform

Comment: Can you show us sample sheets? One is a current sheet. Two is a sheet changed by your script. This is the sheet you don't want. Last one is a sheet you want. These sample sheets will be helpful for people who think the solution.

Comment: you should have padded with zeroes. too late now unless you migrate it. else you need to write a custom sort function (show us your attempts if going that route). the custom sort would need to understand your exact format and manually compare each part, or pad ot then just to compare. 16-T-3 padded would be 16-T-0003 etc

Answer (score 1):

You should adjust the sorting method to account of the peculiarities of the data. Here is one way to do this: the function `splitConvert` processes each string, splitting it by non-word characters and then converting what can be converted to integers (and lowercasing the rest). Then the comparison goes through this array one by one.

```
comboValues.sort(
  function(a, b) {
    var as = splitConvert(a);
    var bs = splitConvert(b);
    for (var i = 0; i < as.length; i++) {
      if (bs[i] < as[i]) return -1;
      if (bs[i] > as[i]) return 1;
    }
    return 0;
  }
);

function splitConvert(str) {
  return str.split(/\W/).map(function(part) {
    var x = parseInt(part, 10);
    return isNaN(x) ? part.toLowerCase() : x;
  });
}
```

This is not the most performance-oriented solution: the split-parse function will be repeatedly called on the same strings as they are being sorted. If this becomes an issue (I don't really think so), one can optimize by having one run of conversion, creating an array of arrays, and then sorting that.